# Is there a linux global variable like $HOME for systemd unit file directories?

Tags: shell-script, systemd

I'm in the process of building bash-script based installer that needs to set up a systemd unit among other things. I could hard-code the typical systemd unit file locations like `/etc/systemd/system` or `/usr/lib/systemd/system` but I'd like to be able to have the script be able to detect the system's preferred location for adding a new unit file and service.

I could certainly do this by using `find` and looking for existing service unit files, but I wanted to avoid adding too much complexity if there's already an existing global variable (like `$HOME`) I could call on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, all systems are the same.  The manpage offers a number of insights -  https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html

```
System Unit Search Path

/etc/systemd/system.control/*
/run/systemd/system.control/*
/run/systemd/transient/*
/run/systemd/generator.early/*
/etc/systemd/system/*
/etc/systemd/system.attached/*
/run/systemd/system/*
/run/systemd/system.attached/*
/run/systemd/generator/*
…
/usr/lib/systemd/system/*
/run/systemd/generator.late/*
```

If you are building the service unit file then you should probably install the files in `/etc/systemd/system`, which has the description "System units created by the administrator".

There are a couple places in the code that make it seem very unlikely most of these paths could be changed, and that `/etc/systemd/system` appears hard coded

- https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/6b87254ad1ecb17e4ef88090c356705e55088c8a/src/core/systemd.pc.in#L41
- https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/b0a5e596224d04ae4d70bb864591152310efac0c/src/basic/path-lookup.c#L609

Comment: Ah good to know that `/etc/systemd/system` is hardcoded for everything. That'll be good enough for my purposes